# Setting default value of dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Please look at the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/judiqunipe/1/edit?html,js,output)

I have created a dropdown type that uses a template (so that I can add the `SELECT ONE` option).  After doing this, I cannot seem to default the dropdown any longer.

According to this [example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-formly/select) this should set the default:

```
vm.model = {dropdown1: 'key1Key'};
```

This sets `dropdown1` to `key1Key` down within model...but no default is selected.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect value in ng-options for what you are trying to achieve.

I suggest trying:

```
    option.Key as option.Value for option in to.options
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I was too busy looking at formly.  Should have peeked into `ng-options`, too.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, You should use ng-model to set the default value of the dropdown.

The value of the variable assigned to ng-model should contain the value of the option.

E.g.

```
vm.list = [{Id : 1, Text : 'Text 1'},{Id : 2, Text : 'Text 2'}];
vm.selected = 1; //  Id used as value so, set to 1 to assign it as default.
```

Then,

`<select ng-model="vm.selected">
       <option ng-repeat="option in vm.list" value="{{option.Id}}">{{option.Text}}</option>
 </select>`

I hope it helps.